# Disable copy of selected portion of a webpage rendered by React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy

I am trying to disable copy option for certain part of my webpage. I know that there is no way to disallow user to copy if he sets his mind to it but I just don't want a simple copy of certain section to not work (select + right click or ctrl+c) to work.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the following styles to prevent the user from selecting the text superficially like so:

```
user-select: none;
```

```css
p {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p> Some sample text that you cant select </p>
```

[Details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)